# Reading data from mobile sensor and connecting to WireCloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to develop my first application which is reading a mobile's sensor data as Accelerometers and then sending this data to wirecloud mashup, is there a way i could achieve this?
Certain GEs? or Could i connect it to CKAN and upload the data as JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this integrating Wirecloud, Orion Context Broker and the IoT specific Generic Enablers (GEs), IoT agents and IDAS. If you need authentication and basic authorization, you can use KeyRock IdM and Wilma PEP Proxy.

I think [this presentation (Developing your first application using FIWARE)](http://cattelefonica.webs.upv.es/Fiware/developingyourfirstapplicationusingfiware.pdf) can help you. It has explanations and diagrams about the GEs used and how to integrate them.

I hope this can help you.